# Getting a "NetLogon" error when registring trying to regster a new agent under "NT Authority\System"

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I'm trying to set up a new deployment group, with the creation of a new dedicated (windows) agent. The web UI is nice, as it is able to generate the power shell commands to get that done. But unlike the documentation, I don't get the little check box that says "include PAT", but this is not the problem here. (Maybe this is because I'm using a AzureDevops on premise Server version instead of the cloud managed service?)

**Here is my problem.** I run the script, I just give the PAT, and I let the default service user for the agent which is `NT Authority\System` (`AUTORITE NT\Système` in french, as I'm using a self hosted french windows VM). Finally the process exits with the following error. when trying to start the service: `Cannot start service vstsagent.<devopsservername>.<agentpoolname>.<agentmachinename> on computer '.'.`

When I go to the event viewer, I can see the following:

```
This computer is configured as a member of a workgroup, not as a member of a domain. The Netlogon service does not need to run in this configuration.
```

Whenever I go to the service pannel and try to start it manually I still get the same problem. When I switch user to "LocalSystem", everything goes fine...

**What goes wrong?** Why is it complaining about NETLOGON? Aren't "NT Authority\System" and "LocalSystem" the same account?
Could it be related to the fact I'm using a french OS? (unable to select the relevant account by default? or something in this mood?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after having tested the same scenario with a standard en/US host running the agent, we do not get the problem.
I suspect this is due to the french language where `NT Authority\System` is named `AUTORITE NT\Système` that can not be matched (due maybe to the `é` character?)

Answer (score 1):

[LocalSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/localsystem-account?redirectedfrom=MSDN) account is a built-in Windows Account. It is the most powerful account on a Windows local instance (More powerful than any admin account). It is part of `NT Authority\SYSTEM`.

As a workaround, we could open Control Panel / Administrative Tools / Services / NETLOGON and change it from automatic to manual and then stop it, then try it again.

**Update1**

My machine language is English and the test result as shown below.

Power shell:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Yes, but NetLogon was already set to manual, and already stopped. This is what I don't understand...

Comment: This issue may be related to machine language, would you mind changing the language to English and trying again?

Comment: Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: It's not a blocking issue, as I found a workaround. Iwill try to set up a new agent on an english machine to see if it is a culture related problem.

Comment: Hi @Christophe, Glad to hear that your problem has been solved. Would you mind sharing the workaround here as an answer? It could help other community members who get the same issues. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: Hi @VitoLiu , the workaround was just to switch the service's identity to LocalSystem. I still do not understand why I got a NetLogon error as this one was already turned off.

Comment: OK, I took some time to do the test. With an en/US OS there is no problem, the default "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" is found and we do not get any error.